# Get JTA transaction timeout value in WebLogic

Tags: java, timeout, weblogic, transactions, jta

Is there a way to get JTA transaction timeout value? UserTransaction interface has only setTransactionTimeout method. Is there a specific way of getting its value in WebLogic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want the default, you can use [weblogic.management.configuration.JTAMBean](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/wlsmbeanref/core/index.html).

Comment: Thanks, but no, I actually want the timeout of the current transaction as it may differ from default.

Answer (score 2):

In WLS 10.2, you can use the WLS custom extension `weblogic.transaction.Transaction` and then call `getTimeToLiveMillis()`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no actual solution to determine current transaction timeout value with simple API call.

As a solution I've used the advice from Wayne above to get the default value. Also as all non-default values I set myself based on configuration file, I read/cache it again when there is a need to get the value for current transaction timeout.